# Pygame pressing key to move a Rect

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame

I am trying to keep pressing a key and move the square automatically. I've tried to change `pygame.key.get.pressed()` to `pygame.key.get.focused()`, but still nothing.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("shield hacking")
JogoAtivo = True
GAME_BEGIN = False
# Speed in pixels per frame
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
cordX = 10
cordY = 100


def desenha():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    quadrado = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (cordX, cordY ,50, 52))
    pygame.display.flip();    


while JogoAtivo:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        print(evento)
    #verifica se o evento que veio eh para fechar a janela
        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
               JogoAtivo = False
               pygame.quit();
        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
               print('GAME BEGIN')
               GAME_BEGIN = True
               desenha();        
        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and GAME_BEGIN:   
                   speedX=-3
                   cordX+=speedX
                   desenha()
        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and GAME_BEGIN:
                   speedX=3
                   cordX+=speedX
                   desenha()
```

UPDATED THE CODE, BUT STILL THE SAME PROBLEMS (included KEYDOWN event).

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("shield hacking")
JogoAtivo = True
GAME_BEGIN = False
# Speed in pixels per frame
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
cordX = 10
cordY = 100


def desenha():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    quadrado = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (cordX, cordY ,50, 52))
    pygame.display.flip();



while JogoAtivo:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        print(evento)
    #verifica se o evento que veio eh para fechar a janela
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
               JogoAtivo = False
               pygame.quit();
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   print('GAME BEGIN')
                   GAME_BEGIN = True
                   desenha();        
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                   speedX=-3
                   cordX+=speedX
                   desenha()
        if evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             if evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   speedX=3
                   cordX+=speedX
                   desenha()
```

Comment: Just updated the code, but still the same problem: *set KEYDOWN as conditionals to keys

Comment: If you write your code in english it probably will be more people able to help. Also, you're using three if-statements checking the same condition. You can put all code under one if-statement. Python usually don't use semicolon (`;`) at end of lines, and in your case you could remove them all from your program.

Comment: Also, what are the problems in your script? You have to specify. The problems I can see is the structure of the code. Maybe you should check out some tutorials first? [Here's a short one to help you get started](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/3959/introduction-to-pygame/14697/a-simple-game#t=201610121006455484266)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `get_pressed()` in `for evento` loop because when you keep pressed key then key doesn't generate events and `pygame.event.get()` returns empty list so `for` does nothing.

When you start pressing key then system generates single even `KEYDOWN`, when you stop pressing key then system generates single even `KEYUP` but system doesn't generate `KEYDOW` events between this two moments (when you keep pressed key).

You have to use `get_pressed()` (and other code) after `for` loop.

```
for evento in pygame.event.get():
    print(evento)
    if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
          JogoAtivo = False
          pygame.quit();

# after for loop

pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if pressed_keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
           print('GAME BEGIN')
           GAME_BEGIN = True
           desenha();        
if pressed_keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and GAME_BEGIN:   
               speedX=-3
               cordX+=speedX
               desenha()
if pressed_keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and GAME_BEGIN:
               speedX=3
               cordX+=speedX
               desenha()
```

or (more or less)

```
for evento in pygame.event.get():
    print(evento)
    #verifica se o evento que veio eh para fechar a janela
    if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
           JogoAtivo = False
           pygame.quit();
    elif evento.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if evento.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
               print('GAME BEGIN')
               GAME_BEGIN = True
        elif evento.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
               speedX = -3
        elif evento.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               speedX = 3
    elif evento.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if evento.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
               speedX = 0


# after loop

if GAME_BEGIN:
    cordX += speedX                   
    desenha()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong, I may not be quite understanding what you asked), but it looks like what you are trying to do is press a key, keep the key held down, and have pygame continually process KEYDOWN events as you are holding the key down.  In pygame, this does not work, but you *can* handle holding a key down in a different way.  Just think:  if you start holding a key down, it creates a KEYDOWN event.  When you let go of that key, it generates a KEYUP event.  So therefore, the key is being held down *after* you push the key down and *before* you let it go.  The following code explains the concept through example:

```
import pygame, sys, time
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])
a_pressed = False

while 1:
    time.sleep(.2)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                a_pressed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                a_pressed = False
    if a_pressed == True:
        print '"A" is currently being pressed down.'
```

I haven't been able to test the code (using school computer), but this should print the above message while you are holding the "A" key, at approximately 5 times per second (this is a lazy way of limiting fps).  The same applies not only for all keys, but also dragging with the mouse.